# Destructing objects with private destructors

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm currently working on a program that generates C++ code. This generated C++ code sometimes needs to destruct a Class, so it uses

```
ptr->~MyClass();
```

, because this works in all corner cases (including for example inherited destructors). Or so I thought: If there is a private destructor:

```
class MyClass {
    ~MyClass();
};
```

Then `ptr->~MyClass();` will be  a compile time error.

Any ideas what I could do? If the destructor is private, the generated code should either call it anyway or throw an exception or exit the program.

Note that my code generatator does not know which class has a private destructor and which class does not have a private destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
auto destruct(T* t) -> decltype(t->~T()) { t->~T(); }

auto destruct(void*) { /*  throw, exit, ... */ }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d200f806ffe815)

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer not to call the destructor explicitly! It's called automatically when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: The code is a wrapper for an interface with a different programming language. So yes, I need to call it explicitly, because otherwise, it won't get called, because both languages have different scopes.

Comment: This is good advice, but only applicable in some cases (not in my case). You should PREFER to not call the destructor explicitly, but sometimes you need to.

Comment: Smart pointers aren't smart across language boundaries.